# Matching consecutive words in a sentence

Tags: powershell

I would like to match a partial sentence against another string.

In the example below I want it to print "True" if it finds Hello then Mich then Brooklyn in the other string. This is how it works in Linux, I don't see anyone doing this in PS. I would like to create a string that has the wildcards in it already to simplify coding.

```
$Keywords = "Hello.*Mich.*Brooklyn"
```

**Example 1**

```
$Sentence = "Hello I am Michael From Brooklyn New York"
if ($Keywords -Match $Sentence) {
    Write-Host("True")
} else {
   Write-Host("False")
}
```

Desired output:
True

**Example 2**

```
# Output should be 'False'
$Sentence = "Hello I am Michael From QUEENS New York"
if ($Keywords -Match $Sentence) {
    Write-Host("True")
} else {
   Write-Host("False")
}
```

Desired output: False

Comment: You have the LHS and RHS reversed. The RHS of the operator should be the regex string. It should be `$Sentence -match $Keywords`. If you are comparing a string with a string, `-match` will return `True` or `False` as is.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Ah it's backwards to the Linux shell =~ command thanks. If you respond I will vote yours up

Comment: Thanks. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-hand side (LHS) and right-hand side (RHS) of the operator are reversed. The RHS of `-match` needs to be the regex string. The following will give the desired result.

```
$Sentence -match $Keywords
```

If you are comparing a single string against a regex string using `-match`, `True` will be returned if there is a match. `False` is otherwise returned. When the LHS is an array rather than a single string, then the items in the collection that successfully match are returned instead.

Comment: Thanks!  This was very helpful!

Comment: if you think it's worthy question upvote it, I don't see it anywhere for powershell.